# How to use latest SequencedSet interface (java21) with jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, java-21, sequencedset

I have a class with a `SequencedSet` field, but I can't find a way to make it work with jackson deserialization.

```java
class MyClass {
    private SequencedSet<UUID> ids;

    public SequencedSet<UUID> getIds() {
        return ids;
    }

    public void setIds(SequencedSet<UUID> ids) {
        this.ids = ids;
    }
}
```

I get this error

> InvalidDefinition Cannot find a deserializer for non-concrete Collection type [collection type; class java.util.SequencedSet, contains [simple type, class java.util.UUID]]

Edit: I defaulted to using LinkedHashSet instead of SequencedSet

Comment: What actual implementation class do you expect when you only specify the interface `SequencedSet`?

Comment: It's nothing to do with `SequencedSet`. It would be exactly the same if you had tried to use `Set`. You can still achieve what you want by getting Jackson to create a `LinkedHashSet` and casting it yourself to a `SequencedSet`.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I made just the setter using `LinkedHashSet`. Then at least the field and the getter may use `SequencedSet`.

```java
class MyClass {
    private SequencedSet<UUID> ids;

    public SequencedSet<UUID> getIds() {
        return ids;
    }

    public void setIds(LinkedHashSet<UUID> ids) {
        this.ids = ids;
    }
}
```

This requires (de)serialization via getters/setters (or constructors) instead of direct field access though.

To the question in the comments which implementation I expected: `LinkedHashSet` or similar because that preserves the properties of a `SequencedSet`: The order is preserved and no duplicates are allowed. For `Set` and `List` Jackson automatically selects concrete implementations too.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post your code?